# ReactJS - Fetch as Google only works for homepage but not other routes?

Tags: reactjs, google-search-console

I used create-react-app to create my react app.

I have it deployed on AWS Cloudfront + S3. Everything seems to work when I visit the site: https://www.remotecareers.io

However, when I try using the "Fetch and Render" feature of Fetch as Google, I see this:

[image]

It's weird that the `This is how a visitor to your website would have seen the page:` part is empty. However, my main issue is when I try to do the same thing for the non-root routes.

For example, I have this page: https://www.remotecareers.io/remote-jobs/new. It looks like it's working fine. However, when I try fetching it through google it says it's `Not Found`.

[image]

It says the same thing in the new Google Search Console too:

[image]

So far even to get just the `This is how Googlebot saw the page:` part to work, I installed and added:

```
import "babel-polyfill"; // I tried this by itself as well as with the 2 below
import "url-search-params-polyfill";
import "whatwg-fetch";
```

What's weird is that the homepage is (partially) working but the rest of the pages aren't being scanned at all. I thought it might be because I wa missing the `robots.txt` file so I added it but it seems to not have any affect (https://www.remotecareers.io/robots.txt). Can someone help me?

Comment: Is your react app server rendered? From my experience, relying on googlebots to run javascript to render the app is not very reliable. I assume your server only return a blank HTML document with some script tags that load the javascript needed to render the app? If so, try looking into server side rendering react app.

Comment: @Jackyef Hi Jacky. I'm hosting it on AWS S3 though, so is server side rendering still an option? Or do I have to switch to Heroku or something?

Comment: I have added my answer below. In short yes, you need a dedicated NodeJS web server to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, relying on googlebots to run javascript to render the app is not very reliable. For best SEO performance, you need to server render your react app.

You will need a dedicated NodeJS server that will render your react app, then send down the rendered HTML to the browser. The browser will receive the HTML response, which includes some script tags as well. After the scripts are loaded, it will run and hydrate your react app so that everything works properly.

Try reading this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/demystifying-reacts-server-side-render-de335d408fe4) to get you started on this topic.

Comment: Great I'll try it and let you know how it goes

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.